# Long long is 8 bytes, meaning?

Tags: c++, c, long-long

I've read the answers to the question of why `sizeof(long long)` is 8 on most systems, but I'm still not sure how to interpret the meaning of them.

One of the reasons given is that there is a lot of code 'out there' which assumes that `sizeof(long long) <= sizeof(size_t)`. That makes sense. Then there are all kinds of views on architecture conventions and brands, etc. I don't even want to get into those debates about the history of the convention. There are also reasons given that `long long` can be any size according to standard, but I think that is not really what concerns me.

What I want to know is how to interpret the difference **now** between the fact that `sizeof(long long)` returns 8 but that a `long long` actually is 16. Should it be interpreted as a historical remnant that applies only to the `sizeof` operator, or is there an underlying address pointer associated with that fact, so that operations on a `long long` are executed in 8 byte increments?

Sizeof (signed) long v4: 8
Value of (x at 2147483647)v4: 7fffffff

Sizeof long long v5: 8
Value of (x at 9223372036854775807)v5: 7fffffffffffffff

Comment: How is a `long long` supposed to be 16 bytes?  `long long` should be a 64 bit type and as such it should be of size 8 bytes.  check this out: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: I added clarifying information.

Comment: still don't understand where the 16 comes from

Comment: I was counting each 'nibble' as a 'byte'. My question should be why long returns 8 but only hold 4bytes.

Comment: The original question was if a long long is treated as a unit by the processor, or not. Apparently it is, to the point that even a long is given 8bytes, though it only uses 4. That is a different question, though. Thank you for your help with the original question.

Comment: I've read both questions you posted and I am still confused of what you are asking.

Comment: I was confused about what question I was asking as well, Thomas, which is the reason for my asking a question. The question turns out to be whether we ought to anticipate the elimination of the 4byte long, or not.

Answer (score 4):

According to the standard, `long long` is at least 64 bits, or say, 8 bytes.

On most machines today, it is 8 bytes long. `sizeof` (BTW, an operator, not a function) returns its size, you can count on it. There's no way `sizeof(long long)` is `8` while the size of `long long` is `16`.

Comment: what if a16 bit `char`?

Comment: Perhaps quote the paragraph in question.

Comment: I've confused a byte with a nibble, my question should be why a long returns 8, when it only holds 4bytes.

Comment: @MarkLeavenworth `long`? It's a differnt type than `long long`.

Comment: The follow-up question would be why sizeof(long) returns 8, but only holds 4bytes. That is not really the original question, but I think I will post it anyway out of curiosity. Thank you for helping with the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The longest standard data type is 8 bytes (64 bits) on most of the systems, Which is `long long`.

---

In addition you can include `limits.h` which library contains defined values for each data type and the space it occupies on your system.

---

A slight update during the fact I've encountered some level of interest over `long`.
It is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits (or 4 bytes) long. So as `long int` (though in that case, `long` is rather a length modifier).

Comment: `long long` is very rarely (if ever) 4 bytes, even on 32bit systems. `long` varies greatly though.

Comment: Yes. I thought `might` in english means.. very unlikely and is less likely than "may". Though I had a dos pc and `long long` was 32 bits. x32 bit arch pc with x32 bit hardware

Comment: the standard now gauntness a long long to be a minimum of 64 bits.  See C++11/C11 standard 5.2.4.2.1.  `maximum value for an object of type unsigned long long int
ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615 // 2^64 − 1`

Comment: Again, what if `char` is not 8 bits?

Comment: Okay. I will drop the idea of it to be 4 bytes. Not useful enough.

Comment: @user3528438 `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.  see 5.3.3.1 of the C++11 standard.  everything else dealing with sizes is based of of that.

Comment: @NathanOliver then, if `long long` is 64bit and `char` is 16bit then what's the `sizeof(long long)`?

Comment: @user3528438 A `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.  It can be more.

Comment: In "The longest standard data type is guaranteed to be 8 bytes (64 bits) on most of the systems", drop "guaranteed to be".

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere there is a confusion and I am not sure where it is, because you don't say where you get your numbers from, so I will try to clarify the basics.

`sizeof` returns by definition the number of bytes a type occupies. On all modern systems a byte is composed of 8 bits, but on some esoteric or old architectures a byte has other number of bits. `CHAR_BIT` from `limits.h` tells you how many bits there are in a byte. But again, on all modern architectures that's 8.

> sizeof(long long) returns 8 but that a long long actually is 16.

That is not true. If `sizoef(long long)` is 8 then `long long` is 8 bytes long.

> The follow-up question would be why sizeof(long) returns 8, but only holds 4bytes.

Again, not true. If `sizeof (long)` is `8` then `long` holds 8 bytes.

> The question turns out to be whether we ought to anticipate the elimination of the 4byte long, or not.

Not a chance in hell. One of the pillars of C and C++ is backwards compatibility. Removing a fundamental type would break practically every program on the planet.

If you ask if there is any use of the type `long` when `int` and `long long` seem to cover everything then again the answer is `int` and `long long` don't cover everything. There are system like e.g. arduino where `sizeof int == 2`, `sizeof long == 4` and `sizeof long long == 8`.

Comment: I was using a 64 bit hardware computer with 32 bit software at the time, when Apple switched from 32 to 64 bit. My software was in the process of updating.

Comment: Point granted. I apologize. My American hyperbole has caused unintended offense to my friends.

Comment: @MarkLeavenworth apology accepted, although that was not my intention. I wanted to know how I have offended you.

Comment: @MarkLeavenworth oh, I didn't even realized it's an old question. I just saw it on the main page feed.

Comment: I deeply and sincerely apologize. My comment was directed at the diabolic self-appointed 'leaders' of this forum, and not at you or your comment. I appreciate your efforts to help myself and others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that part of your system had been switched over to 64 bit and part of your system was still operating as 32 bit.